# Assigning string from a csv cell to a variable using pandas/python

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, variables

For example, at some point in my `csv` file there is a `cell` with the string 'username', which is in say cell b6 (note: this is not a row or column header). 2 cells to the right of this, there is the associated value for the 'username', let's say it is 'Jason', in b8.

How can I copy the string 'Jason' and assign it to a variable x for future use?

Ideally I would like to bypass having the code interact with excel in any way

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You'll find you'll get better answers, faster, if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate your problem.  At the very least, provide example data and desired output.  This not only makes it easier to help you, but for others who find your post in the future, it'll be easier for them to understand as a reference.

Comment: You might be interested in the first two chapters of the [pandas cookbook](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html), which are [reading csv data](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jvns/pandas-cookbook/blob/v0.1/cookbook/Chapter%201%20-%20Reading%20from%20a%20CSV.ipynb) and [selecting data from dataframes](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jvns/pandas-cookbook/blob/v0.1/cookbook/Chapter%202%20-%20Selecting%20data%20&%20finding%20the%20most%20common%20complaint%20type.ipynb).

Comment: Content fomatting